# apk is working with emulator but getting application not installed message in device

Tags: android

My problem is like application working in emulator and the same apk is not working in device(getting application not installed message).
My application using libraries such as twitter,cordova etc.

If am building the same code in previous developer machine then that apk is working in device.

I am using windows 7 enterprise edition 64 bit.

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: Is there any other error attached to the error "Application not installed" like "Insufficient space" or something ..

Comment: Could You see error message ? plugin via usb or adb over wifi, I had the same Issue not so long time ago, in console it was some messages, something like permission error, but solution was not concerning them.

Comment: How about when you test it on your real phone, and what is the difference between both emulators?

Comment: its tablet application.when i am installing to tablet then getting application not installed message.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I had to sign the .apk before installing it on a real device. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I am getting the same message even after signing the apk.I am able to install signed apk in my emulator .